# Folder items not showing?

Tags: nautilus, shared-folders

After copying some files via Network from other shared computer folder's files(videos), files are not showing but it consumed the size.

And you know how to solve it, right?

---

After doing that it said.

what will i do i do? withi these.

```
ls: cannot access One Piece 352.mkv: Input/output error
ls: cannot access One Piece 353.mkv: Input/output error
ls: cannot access One Piece 354.mkv: Input/output error
total 2290096
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    20480 Nov 10 22:29 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     4096 Nov 10 22:04 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62813496 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 351.mkv
-????????? ? ?    ?           ?            ? One Piece 352.mkv
-????????? ? ?    ?           ?            ? One Piece 353.mkv
-????????? ? ?    ?           ?            ? One Piece 354.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62844148 Jul  6  2011 One Piece 355.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 69234398 Jul  6  2011 One Piece 356.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62845183 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 357.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62827963 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 358.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62838780 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 359.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62837104 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 360.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62813792 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 361.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62842042 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 362.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62843543 Jul  6  2011 One Piece 363.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62832558 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 364.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62820286 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 365.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62846936 Jul  6  2011 One Piece 366.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62837075 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 367.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62851209 Jul  6  2011 One Piece 368.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62837409 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 369.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62812522 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 370.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62851644 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 371.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62838500 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 372.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62370747 Jul  6  2011 One Piece 373.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62480550 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 374.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62371425 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 375.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62413653 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 376.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62287449 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 377.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62284548 Jul  6  2011 One Piece 378.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62448127 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 379.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62434587 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 380.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62275388 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 381.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62294947 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 382.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 66761802 Jul  4  2011 One Piece 383.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62303555 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 384.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 62358213 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 385.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 66140516 Jul  4  2011 One Piece 386.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 65891269 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 387.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 65912631 Jul  3  2011 One Piece 388.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 65694129 Jul  5  2011 One Piece 389.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 65970090 Jul  4  2011 One Piece 390.mkv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal, go to that directory:

```
cd directory-name
```

Then list ALL files:

```
ls -la
```

*It is probably a file permission/ownership issue.*

---

**Update**

The file copy process has left these files 'owned' by root. You could change that with: `chown OWNER:GROUP`

But, some of the files were also copied incorrectly (or corrupted), and you may need to re-copy them ..

Comment: I looked at in that and it is root. Still not showing.